# My Facebook App also works inside iOS/android apps?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

Can a custom FB web app be used inside the iOS / android FB apps? Docs are not very clear on that. You can create Bookmarks for native apps, but I want to have a bookmark pointing to our custom FB web app canvas. The goal is to develop an app that's usable on all platforms.

Comment: I think this is the collective goal :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been making some test and I could'n execute a non native app from facebook app or web page, and it's not easy to load facebook web page in PC mode from a mobile device.

The [official Facebook documentation for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register) says:

> When a user does a search in the Facebook app your app will be visible if it passes a usage threshold. The search results will display apps that have been configured for SSO support. When the user selects your app from the search results they will be directed to your app. If the user had previously authorized your app they will be authenticated when your app is launched.

I guess that for Android will be pretty like this. So if you develop a native app that only shows a WebView pointint to your web (pretty simple by the way in iOS and [android](http://i.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/createsimplebrowserusingwebviewinandroidsimplebrowser)) must work with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Facebook APPs are on Flash, so I don't think that it will work on iOS (Please correct me if I'm wrong with the Flash issue).

On Android, it would be extremely easy, having in mind it works with Flash with 0 problems. You'd just have to implement a WebView on your layout and point to the url of your facebook app.

In general, you can really create applications that work on both systems, iOS and Android, playing with the webView's. However, you have to know that they will never work as if they were written on native code in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, if a developer already has an existing mobile version of their app which is also on Facebook, they are able to create a tab for it that will appear on Facebook for iOS and Facebook for Android. I don't think you can create a bookmark to the webapp version to be seen on a mobile phone. Users can of course bookmark your webapp on their browsers, though.